# No me aparece el evento OnClick!

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Verán, cree un script en Unity para salir del juego, pero, debía de agregarlo al evento OnClick y cuando lo busque no lo encontré, alguien sabe si debe de activarse algo o agregar algún script?Si es de agregar un script me lo podrían dejar aquí?Les  dejo una imagen por si acaso, espero haber sido claro, gracias :/

PD:Estoy utilizando Unity 2018.2.13f1 en modo 2D

Comment: ¡Si te ha servido mi respuesta marcala como correcta para ayudar a otros usuarios!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSRaptor, en añadido a la respuesta de cmanzo hay algo que falta:

Para añadir funciones a tus botones, debes arrastrar un **objeto** que contenga el script. Por tanto, deberás arrastrar al `onClick()` de tu botón un objeto que tenga tu script con la función que quieras utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres agregarlo a un boton....crea un boton(dentro de canvas), dentro en el obejto boton estara el evento OnClick, ahi es donde lo debes agregar.

Comment: Si, a eso me refiero, pero cuando me meto a lo del boton no me sale la ventana "On Click", sabes como resolverlo?